# (React Native) Setting AsyncStorage value but getting garbage when I retrieve it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I am trying to persist login info of a user in AsyncStorage (React Native), so that they don't have to login when they launch the app again. I have the code in place which should do that, but when I try to retrieve the value later, it's showing `{"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}`, which looks like garbage value. What could I possibly be doing wrong here?

My code (styles omitted for clarity):

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";
import { Text, Button } from "react-native";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Constants from "./libs/constants";

const App = () => {
  const onLogin = async (e) => {
    if (e.success)
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(Constants.LOCAL_KEY, JSON.stringify(e));
  };

  const logoutDone = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem(Constants.LOCAL_KEY);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log({ userData: AsyncStorage.getItem(Constants.LOCAL_KEY) });
    // this shows {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}}
  }, []);

  const isLoggedIn = () => {
    let userJSON = AsyncStorage.getItem(Constants.LOCAL_KEY);

    return (
      userJSON != undefined && JSON.parse(userJSON).EmployeeId != undefined
    );
  };

  return !isLoggedIn() ? (
    <Login onLogin={onLogin} />
  ) : (
    <>
      <Text>{JSON.stringify(AsyncStorage.getItem(Constants.LOCAL_KEY))}</Text>
      <Button
        title="Logout"
        onPress={() => {
          logoutDone();
        }}
      ></Button>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Login.js

```
import Constants from '../libs/constants';
import React, {useState} from 'react';

import {
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

const Login = ({onLogin}) => {
  const [Username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [Password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const doLogin = () => {
    fetch(Constants.LOGIN_API_URL, {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify({Username, Password}),
    })
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((s) => {
        onLogin(s);
      });
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <StatusBar hidden={true} />
      <View style={{padding: 0, margin: 0}}>          
        <View style={{padding: 30}}>
          <TextInput
            onChangeText={(text) => setUsername(text)}></TextInput>
          <TextInput
            onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}></TextInput>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => doLogin()}>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign In</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Comment: `AsyncStorage` as it mentions, it is asynchronous. Whatever you see in the console.log of `promise`. Right way would be to use a splash screen to check async'ly to identify if user has already loggedin or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because AyncStorage.getItem returns a promise so you have to await or add a callback. Please update the following piece of your code

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log({ userData: AsyncStorage.getItem(Constants.LOCAL_KEY) });
    // this shows {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}}
  }, []);
```

to this

```
useEffect(() => {
  const storage = async()=>{
    let items = await AsyncStorage.getItem(Constants.LOCAL_KEY);
    console.log(items)
  }
  storage()
}, []);
```

**Note:** Since useEffect doesn't accept an async function we have to declare an async method inside useEffect and execute it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 await Asyncstorage.getItem(Constants.LOCAL_KEY)
```

in Hooks you can write like that

```
useEffect(() => {
  const retrieveData = async() => {
    let items = await AsyncStorage.getItem(Constants.LOCAL_KEY);
    console.log(items)
  }
  retrieveData()
}, []);
```